# Link alias is not displayed in JIRA comment

Tags: hyperlink, comments, jira, alias, markup

Link alias is not displayed in JIRA comment. Why?

Here is the text I am trying out in a comment section:

> [Test link|https://www.google.com/]

Here is what I see in the result of the comment:

[image]

As you can see I do not see an alias, but I see the actual alias markup here.

What am I missing here?

Thank you.

Comment: Possibly off-topic. Perhaps you will ge more attention at https://superuser.com/. See https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/jira

Answer (score 1):

Switch the editor into the *text* mode (not visual) and make the link look like this

```
[Test link|https://www.google.com/]
```

without additional brackets around the url.